# setting a class value as a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, entity-attribute-value

i'm a complete beginner to coding.

i have some javascript that gives me multiple instances of the same class with different values. i would like to create a variable from all instances of that class value, so i can place it in another expression later. the whole thing needs to be able to loop as well, so i want to basically join all the class values in one expression. i hope that makes sense.

this is an example of the class and value (yes, the value has variables already);

```
D.push('<input class="position" id="position" name="position" value="'+ L.oid + ' In Position '+(B + 1)+'" type="hidden" >');
```

I want the value in this to be it's own variable, let's make it var N, so i can later call it up in;

```
D.push('<input id="totals" name="wholething" value="whole thing with '+ N +'" type="hidden">');
```

there will be multiple classes of "position" so for id.totals I need it to tally the values. I understand there needs to be a join, but how and where? help me please

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking.  Can you provide a sample input/output examples?

Comment: here's a sample input: <input id ="position" class="position" type="hidden" name="positon" value="w500sc In Position 1"></input>

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of the input elements with the `position` class, and then iterate over them, obtaining each of their `value`'s.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('input.position');

var joinedValues = "";

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    joinedValues += list[i].value;
}

console.log(joinedValues);
```

Comment: this is giving me an [object NodeList] where i want the list

Comment: Yes `list` is a NodeList, which is like an array, containing all of the `position` elements.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't understand. it's literally posting "object NodeList]" where i want it to list the joined class values.

Comment: See my edit, to join the values, you can append them to a string in the loop.

Comment: thank you so much! this is working. is there a way to make it give a value even if there is only one class value instance? it's only giving me from Position 2 and up when i have more than 1.